# « Avoir la p(e)lote à terre » : l'effet régional du tricot sur la langue parlée du Québec ou une invention ?

Tags: oral, québec, régionalismes, origine-ou-raison, vulgarité

Il y a plusieurs années un député français avait dit au premier ministre du Québec « J'espère que vous n'avez pas trop la *plotte à terre* » ([*Le Devoir*](http://www.ledevoir.com/international/europe/231677/un-ecart-de-langage-qui-intrigue), [*La Presse*](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-soleil/actualites/politique/200902/09/01-825716-plotte-a-terre-les-dessous-dune-gaffe.php)) pour *pas trop fatigué*, un impair loufoque semant une certaine consternation à l'époque...

---

L'absence du *e* dans la prononciation *p(e)lote*, ou le mot *plotte* directement, est un terme vulgaire et ordurier en français parlé du Québec, pour désigner le sexe de la femme et la femme par métonymie etc. (voir au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plotte)). Dans l'article du *Devoir*, on indique que le linguiste de Radio-Canada n'avait trouvé l'expression employant ce mot dans aucun d'une quinzaine d'ouvrage sur le lexique québécois : « Ça ne semble pas venir de l'anglais non plus. On est dans la tradition orale », concluait-il ; [Lionel Meney](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Meney) quant à lui la voit comme une version plus intense d'« être sur les genoux/rotules », l'affaissement musculaire. Enfin pour une dizaine d'euros on peut retrouver l'expression dans un [livre](https://editionsdorbestier.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/pas-facile-pierre-lasbordes-de-bien-parler-quebecois/). Dans le dictionnaire en ligne [*La Parlure*](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/avoir-la-plotte-a-terre/), on voit que ça fait couler beaucoup d'encre virtuelle ; une entrée (51/6) affirme :

> La "plotte" fait aussi référence à la pelote, habituellement de laine
>   pour tricoter. Comme tricoter un vêtement est habituellement long et
>   "fatiguant" la tricoteuse peut s'endormir sur sa chaise et laisser
>   tomber sa pelote. Donc avoir la "plotte à terre" signifie être brisé
>   de fatigue. L'expression s'est perdue dans le temps, mais est belle et
>   bien Québécoise.

Mais est-ce que la tricoteuse tient vraiment la [pelote](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pelote), l'a-t-elle sur ses genoux ou plutôt dans un panier par terre et dans ce cas comment peut-elle tomber ; la pelote serait la pièce de vêtement par métonymie ? Je connais l'expression familière *avoir le caquet à terre (ou [bas](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/avoir-le-caquet-bas/))*, pour la mine basse, qui participe de ce genre d'expression. Plus familièrement pour fatigué on dirait [*claqué*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/claquer/16374?q=claqu%C3%A9#16244) à mon avis. Personnellement je n'ai *jamais* entendu cette expression au Québec dans ma région. J'en devine le sens parce que je reconnais l'idée d'affaissement (être à terre, avoir quelque chose qui est à terre, de manière imagée) caractéristique d'un état physique ou psychologique, ou même d'une pathologie.

---

L'expression *avoir la plotte à terre* est-elle une expression ou simplement un groupe de mots ressemblant à d'autres prototypes d'expressions et dont on peut deviner le sens quand on connaît celui de « plotte » ; participe-t-elle ou a-t-elle déjà participé de la tradition orale au Québec oui ou non et, le cas échéant, est-ce un régionalisme (Rimouski : [le Bas-Saint-Laurent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bas-Saint-Laurent) ??), depuis quand la connaît-on et comment : est-ce l'effet du tricot, de l'affaissement musculaire, ou une pure invention au lexique qui l'explique ?

Comment: Quand on tricote on ne met la pelote ni directement par terre, ni sur ses genoux, et elle est en général protégée pour la préserver des salissures et autres accidents. Par contre la similitude entre le sexe de la femme (forme, toucher, ...) me semble évident. Et femme fatiguée peut très bien être assisse  par terre.  En français argotique Hexagonal il y a *aller au plote* (plotte, pelote, pelotes, etc.), « envoyer quelqu'un au plote » c'est l'envoyer balader, le repousser (de l'argot militaire,  peloton des hommes de troupe punis) . Je doute cependant qu'on puisse faire un rapprochement.

Comment: @Laure *“dans un panier par terre”*: ça correspond bien à la manière habituelle. Intéressant, par ailleurs, ce terme homophone au masculin. Je ne le connaissais pas. Je doute aussi du lien, mais qui sait?

Comment: Je confirme par ailleurs avoir déjà rencontrée cette expression à quelques reprises avant ce fameux impair ayant défrayé les manchettes. Je dirai simplement que je ne l'avais pas entendue à l'Oratoire Saint-Joseph ni à la Maison de la littérature, et que je ne l'avais pas non plus lue dans une traduction récente de _Critique de la raison pure_ d'Emmanuel Kant.

Comment: Lancer des _pelotes_ de neige : _Les élèves se sont amusés à se peloter pendant toute la récréation_ (1930, [Glossaire](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf)). Étrangement on aurait peut-être pu entendre celle-là en face de l'Oratoire à une autre époque, mais aujourd'hui on comprendrait bien différemment...

Comment: @deLaDauversière Dans ce dernier emploi pelote = boule. Une pelote de neige c'est une boule de neige. Cf la pelote basque.

Comment: @Laure Merci, oui je sais pour la balle/boule j'avais vu ça quand l'OCR avait _juté_ au jeu de paume dans un discours célèbre. C'est une curiosité ici mais c'était simplement pour montrer que ces sens-là sont disparus au Québec moins de 100 ans après, semble-t-il. Comment sait-on quand tel ou tel élément d'une tradition orale s'est manifesté au juste ? Là Feelew l'a entendu donc ce ne serait pas une invention et j'espère que d'autres vont jeter un coup d’œil, éventuellement dire où et quand, trouver d'autres références. Merci aussi pour l'article !

Comment: J'ajouterais que c'est peut-être la pelote basque qui a permis que l'équipe du député dont je parlais en question puisse penser que dire ça soit possiblement compris dans un sens similaire au Québec. Ce serait ce qui a facilité le malentendu pour ainsi dire. C'est ce que je me dis.

Comment: Je trouve étrange l'affirmation *(par un expert québécois de la langue française)* selon laquelle nous sommes dans la tradition orale. Si la langue orale est seule dépositaire de ce tour de langue, comment un politicien étranger en devient-il informé? Via des contacts sur le terrain? Ils semblent avoir fait défaut à notre expert interne, mais supposons-le. Si donc les conseillers du politicien (ou lui-même) ont leurs contacts en place, quel piètre système de vérification interne n'a pas su prévoir ce que 6 millions (moins les plus obtus) ont immédiatement compris comme une fabuleuse bourde?

Comment: @Feelew Ils ont trouvé ça sur un site web en France dans leur lexique particulier dont on trouve un extrait à la fin de l'article dans _La Presse_. Ils semblent aussi avoir associé ça à « avoir la tête à l'envers ». Ça me fait penser à quand on est debout sur les mains, mais moi je dirais _me sentir à l'envers_, mais c'est pas _fatigué_ ça, et la référence directe à la tête c'est surtout pour des états comme l'étourdissement/mal, je sais pas trop, quand c'est pas littéral. C'est par ailleurs possible qu'ils aient mis la main sur un truc plus usuel dans une région via le site ? Merci.

Comment: Dans la mesure où en France plottes signifie en argot testicules, nous avions déjà le quiproquo des gosses (enfants en France), un député aurait du éliminer cette proposition d'office. Je me demande dans quelle mesure ce monsieur n'a pas cherché à faire parler de lui en réussi au delà de ses espérances par erreur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne suis pas un expert de la linguistique mais je suis plutôt certain qu'ici on parle de "plotte", le terme vulgaire pour représenter le sexe d'une femme.

Cette expression jouale est très peu utilisée dans les grands centres (Montréal, Québec), je croix effectivement que l'origne viens de l'est de la province où, ils utilisent beaucoup d'expressions régionales. C'est un secteur plus rurale, plus isolé ou l'accès à l'éducation n'était pas facile il y a plusieurs années.

La signification est un grand découragement:

> Un tel a gagné les élections, j'en ai la plotte à terre!

Ou encore une grande fatigue:

> J'viens d'courrir 40 kilomètre, j'ai vraiment la plotte à terre!

Comment: Le jouale est un argot Québécois. Au lieu de dire; "Je vais passer te voir en fin de journée." en jouale ou dirait; "J'vas passer t'vouère dans fin d'journée.". Le jouale est beaucoup axé sur la contraction de mots et le remplacement de certain sons comme "oir" se prononce "ouère".

Comment: Merci ! Pensez-vous qu'on emploie ça qu'on soit une femme ou un homme ? Et bonne Saint-Jean !

Comment: Oui, malgrés l'absurdité de la chose, les hommes peuvent aussi utiliser cette expression. Encore là, c'est une expression très peu utilisée; j'en parlais dans ma famille cette fin de semaine et aucun ne peu se rappeller de la dernière fois qu'ils ont entendu cette expression.